# Populating each section of collection view independently Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, collections, uicollectionview

I have a collection view embedded in a table view so it scrolls vertically and horizontally. It has four sections, Today, This Week, This Month, This Year. I am having trouble understanding how to populate each section with its own data. Right now I am using the below code to populate the collection view but all sections have the same data. How can I populate each section with with its own data?

So if I had an array of images for Today, an array of images for This Week,  an array of images for This Month, and and array of images for This Year, how can I set the image view in its section to the items in the corresponding array? So Today should have the images in the todayImageArray, This Week should have the images in the thisWeekImageArray and so on.

Also I have the delegate and data source of the collection view set to the table view.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
let images: [[UIImage]] = [
    [image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4],
    [image_5, image_6, image_7, image_8],
    [image_9, image_10, image_11, image_12],
    [image_13, image_14, image_15, image_16]
]    

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images[section].count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

    cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a structured data source. Currently, from your code, it looks like you have a single array called `images` and you're using that to both provide the number of items and also to update cell content. But if you need separate sections, you need to model your datasource as such and provide logical responses to datasource and delegate methods in collectionView.

Example simple data source:

```
let simpleDataSource: [[UIImage]] = [
  [image1, image2],
  [image3, image4],
  [image5, image6]
]
```

Example of using this in collectionView methods:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
  return simpleDataSource.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return simpleDataSource[section].count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
  cell.imageView.image = simpleDataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
  return cell
}
```

You should also read through the [documentation for UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will definitely read through the docs again. I tried your code and it is updating all section image views with the first set of data, so referencing your example code, all section image views would be image1 and image2. Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Updated to add a missing `numberOfSections` method, but if you're running this and the same image is in each section, you're not referencing my sample code...

Comment: Thanks @garrettmurray that bit of code you added had an effect. However now all sections contain all data from the array. So each section has: image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6. I had read through the docs on collection views before but your answer is really helping me understand them better so thank you!

Comment: Without seeing your custom cell code, it's hard to tell. Sounds to me like you might be adding an `imageView` in your cell in a place that is causing it to get added to the view hierarchy every time the cell is reused. I'd start by looking there.

Comment: Ill play around with my code and see if I can figure it out. Also, I have updated my post with the current code I have to set up the collection view cell and the image array. Please let me know if you notice anything I might be overlooking! Thanks!

Comment: If you post your custom cell code as well, that would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by custom code? Im happy to add it just not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135898/discussion-between-garrettmurray-and-m1234).

Comment: Great answer! @garrettmurray

Answer (score 0):

Set up an array that has all your images, or better yet structs designed to organize your information better, or image names as in my example, and then use the `numberOfSections` and `indexPath.section` properties to assign those images:

```
let images = [
    ["imageA1", "imageA2"],
    ["imageB1", "imageB2"]
]

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return images[section]
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images[section].count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```